Blazor Server Redirect Causes blazor.web.js to not load from _framework correctly
I have a Blazor NET 8 Web Application. Currently working towards using Cookies as authentication. The login is being handled by a middleware class which does send the unauthorized user to /Login, but the blazor.web.js is not loading with an error of :
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
On a Status Code 302 Redirect
I have been looking all over for answers on how to resolve this.
Service Injection:
// Collection of Services to Inject into the Application
public static IServiceCollection AddServerUI(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
{
    // Add LdapAuthenticationService
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
    services.AddScoped<LdapAuthenticationService>();

    // Bind LdapRoleMappings from configuration and add LdapRoleMappingConfig
    var ldapRoleMappingConfig = new LdapRoleMappingConfig();
    config.Bind("LdapRoleMappings", ldapRoleMappingConfig);
    services.AddSingleton(ldapRoleMappingConfig);

    var ldapServerList = new LdapServerList(config);
    services.AddSingleton(ldapServerList);

    // Adds Blazor Server render mode and components
    services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

    // Configure authentication
    services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
    services.AddScoped<CookieEvents>();

    services.AddAuthentication("Cookies")
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60); // Set the cookie expiration time
            options.SlidingExpiration = true; // Enable sliding expiration
            options.EventsType = typeof(CookieEvents);
        });

    // Configure authorization policies
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", policy =>
            policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
        options.AddPolicy("RequireUserRole", policy =>
            policy.RequireRole("User"));
        options.AddPolicy("RequireManagerRole", policy =>
            policy.RequireRole("Manager"));
        options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();   
    });
    //services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler>();

    // Mud Blazor UI Library Add In
    services.AddMudServices();
    services.AddMudBlazorSnackbar();
    services.AddMudServicesWithExtensions();
    // Add ThemeService
    services.AddScoped<ThemeService>();

    // Load Controllers from /Controllers Folder
    services.AddControllers();

    // IAppConfiguration holds Object with appsettings.JSON Loaded
    services.AddSingleton<IAppConfiguration>(new ServerAppConfiguration(config));

    // Http Client
    services.AddHttpClient();
    // Service to have run only in DEV mode.
    #if DEV

    #endif

    return services;
}

// Build Configuration Injection for Application
public static WebApplication ConfigureServer(this WebApplication app, IConfiguration config)
{
    // Resolve IAppConfiguration from the services
    var appConfiguration = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IAppConfiguration>();

    // Middleware to set Path Base off BaseUrl in AppSettings.json Configuration
    var baseUrl = appConfiguration.BaseUrl;
    app.UsePathBase(baseUrl);

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    }

    // Allow Loading of Static files from wwwroot folder
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    // Route Tables
    app.UseRouting();

    // Authentication and Authorization Configuration
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseAntiforgery();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    /// Configuration loading for Controllers
    app.MapControllers();

    // Maps Components to the Application in Server Render Mode
    app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
            .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

    return app;
}

CustomAuthenticationStateProvider:
        private ClaimsPrincipal _currentUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

        public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_currentUser));
        }

        public void NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(ClaimsPrincipal user)
        {
            _currentUser = user;
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_currentUser)));
        }

CookieEvents.cs:
   public override Task RedirectToLogin(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
   {
       context.RedirectUri = "/Login";
       return base.RedirectToLogin(context);
   }

App.Razor:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <base href="/" />

    <!-- CSS Library Imports  -->
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor.Extensions/mudBlazorExtensions.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="mudex-styles">
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</head>
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- JS Library Imports  -->
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script></script>
</body>

</html>

Routes.Razor
Sets Public Layout to use with /Login
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeView>
            <Authorized>
                <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(MainLayout)" />
            </Authorized>
            <NotAuthorized>
                <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(PublicLayout)" />
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeView>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>


Login.Razor
@page "/Login"
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]



I have tried using this approach:
    public class AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
    {
        public Task HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
        {
            return next(context);
        }
    }

But this doesn't enforce rerouting to /Login
Looking for some advice, I have seen various suggestions around this problem but nothing is really fixing the issue here:
Rerouting to /Login, but having blazor.web.js load in correctly after rerouting.
I have not found a specific solution that matches this problem, apologize if I missed something.

The error usually means the HTML document gets received instead of a JavaScript file, which means your request might get authorized unsuccessfully, you can check the log during authorizing. Meanwhile since you are using MudBlazor, you could check the documents to see if there is any notification.

I determined if I remove :
options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
.Build();
And instead in _Imports.Razor put :
@attribute [Authorize]
That works. Forces back authorization on every page. Something about the Fallback policy in Net 8 is wonky.
